# is it necessary enough in my boss's django code 

Tags: python, django

this is the code:

```
params = dict(request.REQUEST.items())
```

but i think it is not necessary , because i think the request.REQUEST must be the dict ,

so it should be :

```
params = request.REQUEST
```

am i right ?

thanks

Comment: Maybe he wants to create a copy of the original dict values ?

Comment: That alone isn't enough to tell. We need to know what happens to `params`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states:

> For convenience, a **dictionary-like**
>   object that searches POST first, then
>   GET. Inspired by PHP's $_REQUEST.

(Emphasis added)

[HttpRequest.REQUEST](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST) is a dictionary-like item. It is not a dictionary. Your boss might've wanted dictionary operations that weren't on the dictionary-like REQUEST object.

Comment: All the dictionary methods are available to the dict-like REQUEST object, but some of them behave a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

no its not a dict its a subclass, django.http.QueryDict
see [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).

but you are right. there is a items() method.

Answer (score 0):

If this code necessary or not depends on surrounding code, there is not enough information in question.

But generally this code:

```
params = dict(request.REQUEST.items())
```

is not the equivalent of

```
params = request.REQUEST
```

Answer (score 0):

most probably he wanted to make a copy of the object, this may be useful if later in the code there is a modification of this new dictionary.

it is hard to say how it is being used late in the code, but if this is just used as a code shortcut (to not use long form all the time) then your equivalent code is fine.